# How to display null value instead of numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008

table1

```
id name

001 rahim  
002 vijay
```

table2

```
id name amount

003 vijayan 08.00
004 suresh 12.00
```

I want to combine table1 & table2 using union

Query

```
Select id, name, '' from table1 union Select id, name amount from table2
```

Output

```
id name amount

001 rahim 0 -- 0 should not appear, should be null  
002 vijay 0 -- 0 should not apperar, should be null
003 vijayan 08.00
004 suresh 12.00
```

0 is display instead of null, because of table2 amount column is numeric.

How to handle this. Need SQL Query help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 select id, name, amount from table2
 union all 
 select id, name, null from table1
 order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft's msdn site regarding the UNION operator link: [msdn UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

The number and order of columns must match and be type compatible.

User: podiluska uses the correct approach.